# Writing data from a structure to a file in c#

Tags: c#, file, binary, structure

So I am currently attempting to write data from a structure to a binary file and am not having a ton of luck, I was just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of what I may need to implement as most of what I've tried and researched has been unsuccessful. Below is very basic skeleton code attempting to demonstrate my issue.

Thanks!

```
public struct TSensor
{
    byte b1;
    int i1;
    float f1;
}

class Program
{
    const string fileName = "AppSettings.bin";

    static void Main()
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            writer.Write();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to pass in what to write to `writer.Write()`. Did you not read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write(v=vs.110).aspx)? What exactly has you stuck?

Comment: IMO forget about `BinaryWriter` - just the `Stream` is fine. People often have this obsession about using `BinaryWriter`, but it isn't the right tool in almost all cases. I'll see if I can whip up an example...

Comment: Im not sure how to pass the structure data into the writer is my issue. Also what im working on requires it to go to a binary file

Comment: btw: have you considered any of the wide range of serialization frameworks? or are you set on doing it as a raw memory dump?

Comment: Im totally open to solutions - Ill absolutely check out serialization thanks!

Comment: does it have to be binary?  what about using json?

Comment: Yeah it has to be binary

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about raw memory copies, then you will invariably need some `unsafe` code; for example:

```
// write
TSensor val = new TSensor { b1 = 12, i1 = 14, f1 = 42.0F };
byte[] arr = new byte[sizeof(TSensor)];
fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
{
    Unsafe.Copy(ptr, ref val);
}
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, arr);
```

and:

```
// read
byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
TSensor val = default;
fixed (byte* ptr = arr)
{
    Unsafe.Copy(ref val, ptr);
}
System.Console.WriteLine(val.b1);
System.Console.WriteLine(val.i1);
System.Console.WriteLine(val.f1);
```

But: this is going to be brittle to changes, and generally not a great solution. Note I've cheated by using `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` to save some work. If we get IO updates to take `Span<byte>`, then we *might* be able to avoid all of this ugliness and cheat via `Span<T>`'s `NonPortableCast<>` method. But that's all a long way off.

---

Another option is to write the serialization code manually - i.e. you'd have something like (using `BinaryWriter`):

```
writer.Write(val.b1);
writer.Write(val.i1);
writer.Write(val.f1);
```

combined with (using `BinaryReader`):

```
val.b1 = reader.ReadByte();
val.i1 = reader.ReadInt32();
val.f1 = reader.ReadSingle();
```

---

You may find it easier to use a serialization library, though; Json.NET is very popular, for example. Or `XmlSerializer`. If you have a lot of data and want to use binary: something like protobuf-net may be a good choice (I would probably strongly advise *against* the inbuilt `BinaryFormatter`). Serialization libraries deal with an *awful lot* of complexities that probably aren't interesting to you :)